# Need spooky lighting in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,  I'm trying to make a spooky scene in gazebo, but I can't figure out how to add spot lights in gazebo world files.  I can't seem to find a good example.  I see some old examples from, for example, https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/browser/worlds/lights.world , but all of the spot light examples are commented out.  I'm trying to build a spot light that is about 3 meters off the ground and ends up casting a cone of light that is about 1 meter or less in diameter on the floor.   Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10648/need-spooky-lighting-in-gazebo/) by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the unstable version of gazebo:

```
<light type="spot" name="spot" cast_shadows="false">
  <origin pose="0 0 3 0 0 0"/>
  <diffuse rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
  <specular rgba=".2 .2 .2 1"/>
  <attenuation range="10" constant="0.2" linear="0.01" quadratic="0.0"/>
  <direction xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  <spot inner_angle="0.1" outer_angle="0.5" falloff="1.2"/>
</light>
```

if you are using Diamondback or Electric:

```
<model:renderable name="spot">
  <xyz>0.0 0 3</xyz>
  <static>true</static>

  <light>
    <type>spot</type>
    <direction>0 0 -1</direction>
    <diffuseColor>0.0 0.0 1.0</diffuseColor>
    <specularColor>0.0 0.0 0.1</specularColor>
    <attenuation>.1 0.0 0.0</attenuation>
    <range>5</range>
    <spotCone>8.0 10.0 2.0</spotCone> 
  </light>
</model:renderable>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2